# Not able to pass data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, class, android-fragments

I am working on an app in which I have one `Activity` that initially loads a `Fragment`. I am getting IMEI No, Latitude, Longitude in the activity and I pass that data into fragment and also get that data in fragment but I am getting null pointer exception when I get data.

Initially My Account Activity loads Sign Up Fragment and also I am sending data from Account Activity to Sign Up Fragment

// Activity Code  to send data from

// setting SignUp Fragment in Account Activity

```
changeFragments(new SignupFragment());
```

// Now call function GeoLocation and send it to Sign Up Fragment

```
public void GeoLocation() {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("imei_no", imei_number);
    bundle.putString("lat",latitude.toString());
    bundle.putString("long",longitude.toString());
    bundle.putString("postal_code",postalCode);

    SignupFragment fragObj = new SignupFragment();
    fragObj.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

// Now Sign Up Fragment > I am getting these fields where I call Api

```
private void callApi() {

    String imei_no = getArguments().getString("imei_no");
    String  latitude  = getArguments().getString("lat");
    String longitude = getArguments().getString("long");
    String postal_code = getArguments().getString("postal_code");
}
```

I am getting Null Pointer exception here.

Answer (score 0):

```
changeFragments(fragobj);
```

change this line because if you using new SingupFragment at that time it create new object

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the instance of fragment instead of creating new one like:-

```
  public void GeoLocation() {

      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("imei_no", imei_number);
            bundle.putString("lat",latitude.toString());
            bundle.putString("long",longitude.toString());
            bundle.putString("postal_code",postalCode);

            SignupFragment fragobj = new SignupFragment();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

  changeFragments(fragobj);
    }
```

here I call the changeFragments() method inside GeoLocation.